# Error in relationship query N.N generating empty field query in Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm

Error when I try to run `$customer->competitorProduct()->where("product_id", 2)->get()`
I get a error does not exist field "" in the table, while checking the query in Laravel is resembles that the following:

```sql
SELECT `competitor_product`.*, 
       `competitor_product_customer`.`id`          AS `pivot_id`, 
       `competitor_product_customer`.`customer_id` AS `pivot_customer_id`, 
       `competitor_product_customer`.`competitor_product_id` AS `pivot_competitor_product_id`, 
       `competitor_product_customer`.``            AS `pivot_`, 
       `competitor_product_customer`.`status`      AS `pivot_status`,
       `competitor_product_customer`.`created_at`  AS `pivot_created_at`, 
       `competitor_product_customer`.`updated_at`  AS `pivot_updated_at`

FROM   `competitor_product` 
  INNER JOIN `competitor_product_customer` 
     ON `competitor_product`.`id` = `competitor_product_customer`.`` 

WHERE `competitor_product_customer`.`customer_id` = 1 
  AND `product_id` = 2
```

I have an N.N relationship with some tables:

```
DER Image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zh4pV.png
```

Product: [complete code](https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/dHFaRWWU)

```php
<?php
...
class Product extends Model
{
    public function customers(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Customer::class)
            ->using(CustomerProduct::class)
            ->as("customerProduct")
            ->withTimestamps()
            ->withPivot([
                "id",
                "customer_id",
                "product_id",
                ...
             ]);
   }

   public function competitors(): BelongsToMany
   {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Competitor::class)
            ->using(CompetitorProduct::class)
            ->as("competitorProduct")
            ->withTimestamps()
            ->withPivot([ 
              "id",
              "product_id",
              "competitor_id",
                ...
                ...
            ]);
   }
}
```

Customer: [complete code](https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/xzp28saK)

```php
<?php
...
class Customer extends Model
{
    public function competitorProduct()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(CompetitorProduct::class)
            ->using(CompetitorProductCustomer::class)
            ->as('competitorProductCustomer')
            ->withTimestamps();
            ->withPivot([
                 'id',
                 'customer_id',
                 'competitor_product_id',
                 'status'
            ]);
    }

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)
            ->using(CustomerProduct::class)
            ->as('customerProduct')
            ->withPivot([
                'id',
                'customer_id',
                'product_id',
            ...
            ]);
    }
}
```

Competitor: [complete code](https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/0ZUpnjfX)

```php
<?php
...
class Competitor extends Model
{
    public function products(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)
            ->using(CompetitorProduct::class)
            ->as("competitorProduct")
            ->withTimestamps()
            ->withPivot([
                "id",
                "product_id",
                "competitor_id",
                ...
            ]);
    }
}
```

Customer product pivot: [complete code](https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/ME9J3SME)

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;

class CustomerProduct extends Pivot
{
}
```

Competitor product pivot: [complete code](https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/pSLhWf4f)

```php
<?php
...
class CompetitorProduct extends Pivot
{
    public function customers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Customer::class)
            ->using(CompetitorProductCustomer::class)
            ->as('competitorProductCustomer')
            ->withTimestamps();
            ->withPivot([
               'id',
               'customer_id',
               'competitor_product_id',
               'status'
            ]);
    }
}
```

Competitor products x customer products Pivot: [complete code](https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/TXhrEdJy)

```php
<?php
...
class CompetitorProductCustomer extends Pivot
{
}
```

I'm making a something mistake,
or bank relationship or in Eloquent relationship

Any solution?

Comment: why are you using `using()` and `wherePivot()`, those are fairly advanced relationship options. Its a bit hard to tell how your tables are defined, but it sounds like you should be able to greatly simplify those relations.

Comment: @Flame thanks for replying, I'm using `using()` for model extends Pivot to use accessors and mutators, I actually tried to eliminate `WithPivot()` with him, and `wherePivot()` because I'm trying to look for another table field,  I can't make this relationship simpler =(

Comment: pleas post the entire code, not filling the code with "..."

Comment: sorry @AlbertoSinigaglia, I thought it would be very big doubt, add the full code links now

Comment: those `setXxxAttribute` functions in your pastebin are pretty nasty, you should refactor that instead of pasting the same code for every single property. You can possibly override `setAttribute($key, $value)` if you look a bit further into the Eloquent source code. For the actual problem: try setting the other parameters for `belongsToMany()` manually, see https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many